# Working of spider gear in differential axle wheel mechanism

Tags: automotive-engineering, power-transmission

What causes the spider gear to spin about it's own axis while the vehicle is taking a turn?

Comment: A diagram would help, as what you call a "spider gear" may also have a different name, at least, never heard that term when I was studying differentials...

Comment: I am unable to upload a picture.Spider gear is also called planet pinion gear in many references

Comment: If you edit your question, the 6th icon from the left is a representation of an image - looks like a mountain, click on that.

Comment: Did the same thing earlier.Its showing error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it turns about its center is the difference in rotation of the two wheels, which are connected through the sun-gears to planet-pinion gears. By rotating it allows the two sun-gears and consequently, the two wheels go at deferent speeds without either losing power, or having to skid.

And the reason for the difference in the wheels speed is because in a turn the inside wheel has less speed then the outside wheel, having to go around a smaller radius.

[image: diagram of the differential]